# Selenium/WedDriver - Handling a popup window that only sometimes exists?

Tags: java, popup, selenium-webdriver

I'm fairly new to Selenium/webdriver.  I wrote a test case that runs for multiple iterations.  On the first one there's a pop-up window that appears.  However, on follow-up iterations, the pop-up window is not present.  How can I re-write this so it checks for the pop-up before proceeding with the code below?  Thanks

```
    String Parentwindow = oWD.getWindowHandle();

    //Click Search button  -- This will cause the pop-up
    oWD.findElement(By.id("uw_fc_sub_anc")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);


    for(String ChildWindow : oWD.getWindowHandles())
    {
        oWD.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);
    }
    oWD.close();
    oWD.switchTo().window(Parentwindow);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably factor this out into a helper method that did something like the following:

```
public String clickAndFindPopup(WebDriver driver, By locator) {
    // Get the original list of handles to evaluate if a popup
    // needs to be handled.
    List<String> existingHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    //Click Search button  -- This will cause the pop-up
    driver.findElement(locator).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    List<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    windowHandles.removeAll(existingHandles);

    if (windowHandles.size() > 0) {
        return windowHandles.get(0);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
String popupHandle = clickAndFindPopup(driver, By.id("uw_fc_sub_anc"));
if (!popupHandle.equals("")) {
    String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
}
```

The drawback here is that, if you truly only expect the popup on the first iteration, you might dismiss a popup window that you shouldn't be, because you're blindly closing the popup whenever you find one. A much better approach would be to **know** what state you expect the browser to be in when you're automating it, and asserting on it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a try catch to handle "possible notifications". I catch the two possible exceptions generated by a non existing element. This is C# BTW:

```
            public void ClosePossibleRandomNotification()
        {
            bool exists=false;
            try
            {
                Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("..."));
                exists = true;
            }

            catch (ElementNotVisibleException)
            {
                exists = false;
            }

            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                exists = false;
            }

            if (exists){
                try
                {
                    //close the pop up
                }
                catch (ElementNotVisibleException)
                {
                    exists = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Boolean function and use try catch to handle the pop-up